# windows azure web role not available while upgrading

Tags: deployment, azure

I am doing an automatic upgrade through Azure portal. While it is upgrading 1st instance, if I try to access my site through http://xyz.cloudapp.net it doesn't open.

IMO when 1st instance is upgrading, the request should be served from the 2nd instance, but I think this is not happening, that's why I see site unavailable message on my browser.

Is it something which I need to do/configure before I do an upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding matches mine. I would open a support ticket (http://windowsazure.com/support) to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: This situation can happen if there is only a single upgrade domain being defined.

Comment: @Joannes where is this upgrade domain defined?

Comment: Within your service definition file, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517255.aspx

Comment: Note that it defaults to more than one, so you would have had to go out of your way to set it to one.

Answer (score 0):

You want to handle the RoleEnvironmentChanging event properly (i.e. don't set the e.Cancel to true if you don't need to reboot)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg432963.aspx

Comment: surely this event isn't used for upgrading?